# Как обрезать ссылку?

Tags: php

Всем привет.

Допустим, есть ссылка: `http://mysite.ru/cat/page.html`. Как ее с помощью PHP обрезать до `http://mysite.ru` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$a = parse_url('http://mysite.ru/cat/page.html');
print_r($a);
```

Comment: @inferus-vv Пожалуйста, обращайся

Comment: @inferus-vv Эх, что не сделаешь ради ачивок;)

Comment: @romeo Нет, я просто спросил, а потом нашел ответ))

Answer (score 2):

[`explode`](http://www.php.su/functions/?explode) - разбивает строку на подстроки

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = substr('http://mysite.ru/cat/page.html', 0, strlen(http://mysite.ru));
```

Comment: Этот вариант не гибкий. Я ведь не знаю текст ссылки и ее длину

Comment: Ну тогда стоит об этом говорить в описании проблемы и не минусовать ответы за то, что не умеете формулировать вопрос.