# как обрезать ссылку после 4 знака?

Tags: php

Допустим у меня есть ссылка http://website.com/category/sub-category/product/?asdsadasdas

Как обрезать ее до 4 "/" по счету слева чтобы получить http://website.com/category ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как обрезать ссылку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/182892/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, не самое лаконичное решение, но мне оно кажется достаточно гибким и быстрым:

```
<?php

function strip_url($url)
{
    $slashes_found  = 0;
    $slashes_needed = 4;
    
    $length = strlen($url);
    
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i)
    {
        $symbol = $url[$i];
        
        if($symbol === '/')
            ++$slashes_found;
        
        if($slashes_found === $slashes_needed)
            return substr($url, 0, $i);
    }
    
    return $url;
}

$url = 'http://website.com/category/sub-category/product/?asdsadasdas';

echo strip_url($url);

?>
```

С помощью простейшего цикла пробегаем по ссылке и считаем слеши, в нужный момент останавливаемся. Если 4-го слеша в принципе нет, то возвращаем исходную строку.

Comment: Спасибо большое! :)

Comment: уж проще explode() -> join()

Comment: @Jean-Claude, рассматривал такой вариант, счёл более заморочным

Comment: 2 строки кода более заморочные?

Answer (score 0):

Один из способов, использовать [strstr](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strstr.php):

```php
$link = 'http://website.com/category/sub-category/product/?asdsadasdas';
$convertedLink = strstr($link, '/sub-category', true);

print_r($convertedLink); // http://website.com/category
```

Comment: Но это не будет работать для ссылок не с `/sub-category`, а чем-то другим, увы

Answer (score 0):

Вариант [попроще](https://3v4l.org/Fqh00):

```
$url = 'http://website.com/category/sub-category/product/?asdsadasdas';

$data = explode('/',$url);
echo join('/',array_slice($data,0,4));
//string(27) "http://website.com/category"
```